# How to make a "separator"/"ruler" in an Android layout?

Tags: android, layout

I'm making an Android app, and I want to present some data, in TextViews, with different categories. I want it to look something like this:

[image]

I wonder how you can create some "rulers"/"separators" with a header text, which looks something like that. I know you can use custom views, but I'm a bit unfamiliar with them, so if someone want to explain them, that's fine.

One more thing worth pointing out is that I want them to be placeable, previewable and preferrable also editable (the last is not completely nessescary, but it would be nice if you could change the text (that's fine through XML too, as long as different objects can have different headers)) as any other view in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this frequently to make separators:

```
         <View
            android:id="@+id/text_separator"
            android:width=:"fill_parent"
            android:height="1dp"                          // whatever thickness you want
            android:background="@color/black" />         // whatever color you want
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there an easy way to to add a header text on top of the line?

Comment: TextView is what I'd use.  Set the margins on the two to make the textview sit on or nearly on the line as you desire